# Is there a simple way to do form validation in .NET8 Blazor for nested objects?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I looked at the following solution, but NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation is deprecated.

[Blazor Complex Validation between two nested Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859699/blazor-complex-validation-between-two-nested-objects)

Thanks!

Comment: Fluent validation..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0